# Configuring the compile sources of a build phase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a project with many targets.
Every time I create a new target, I am adding a specific class to the Compile Sources and I am setting a compiler flag for that class. How can I apply this setting automatically?

Comment: How many targets are you creating within your project?

Comment: Yoy, are you sure you need such immense amount of targets? A target commonly is used for a variation of an app - eg. FreeVersion vs. PurchaseVersion. To me it sounds a lot as if you are using the concept of a target in a wrong way.

Comment: I am working on 50+ apps that have the same structure, the same libraries used (static and dynamic) and the same project settings. So yes they are variations. I want to add a target and have the build phases settings set automatically if possible.

Comment: Sounds interesting indeed. Unfortunately, I do not have a solution for your enquiry. Just thought I'ld clarify the issue to make sure you are heading into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs to be done by modifying the project file directly. In other words, write a script that will make the changes.

Here's a simple example to add arc flags to a file for all targets.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

USAGE="$0 <filename> ..."

PROJECTFILE="project.pbxproj"
FILES="$*"
COMPILER_FLAGS="\"-fobjc-arc\"";

if [ "${FILES}" = "" ] ; then
    echo ${USAGE};
    exit 1 ;
fi

if [ ! -f "${PROJECTFILE}" ] ; then
    echo "Cannot find ${PROJECTFILE} - Please run from within the .xcodeproj directory";
    exit 1 ;
fi


cp ${PROJECTFILE} ${PROJECTFILE}.bak
for f in ${FILES}; do
    echo "Adding flags for $f" ; 
    sed -ie "s/\(${f}.*{ *isa *= *PBXBuildFile.*\)};$/\\1 settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = ${COMPILER_FLAGS}; }; };/g" "${PROJECTFILE}"
done
```